# How to get the target of a 2 nonlinear eunction/equation system to solve it using steepest descent method C#?

Tags: c#, matlab, nonlinear-functions

so I have the steepest descent algorithm for nonlinear equation solving in MATLAB. I'm trying to get it to work in C#. I've already rewritten most of it, but now I'm stuck at the part, where I'm supposed to get a target of the 2 function/equation system.

The target function in MATLAB :

```
%     Target function
function rez=target(x)
rez=f(x)'*f(x)/2;
return
end
```

`f(x)` is definded there :

```
function fff=f(x)
   fff=[x(1)^2+x(2)^2-2;
     x(1)^2-x(2)^2];
return
end
```

The code that I have in C# so far (I have the input of functions and the gradient function with the partial derivatives) :

```
    // System of 2 nonlinear functions
    Vector<double> Func(double x1, double x2)
    {
        // First function of the system
        double f = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x1 / 2), 3) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos(x2 / 2), 2) - 0.5;
        // Second function of the system
        double s = Math.Pow(x2 - 3, 2) + Math.Pow(x1, 2) + x1 * x2 - 4;
        return Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[] { f, s });
    }

    // Gradient of a 2 nonlinear functions system
    Vector<double> Gradient(double x1, double x2)
    {
        // Partial derivative of function1 by x1
        double f1 = 1.5 * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x1 / 2), 2) * Math.Cos(x1 / 2);
        // Partial derivative of function1 by x2
        double f2 = -0.5 * Math.Sin(x2);
        // Partial derivative of function2 by x1
        double s1 = 2 * x1 + x2;
        // Partial derivative of function2 by x2
        double s2 = 2 * x2 - 6 + x1;

        return Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[] { f1, f2, s1, s2 });
    }
```

The whole algorithm of steepest descent in MATLAB (you can see where that `target(x)` function is used) :

```
eps=1e-5;
step0=0.5;
step=step0;
itmax=10  % amount of how many times the direction of movement can be changed
x=[-3;4]; % start          
for iii=1:itmax

grad=gradient(x); 
target1=target(x);
for j=1:30  % moving that direction, where the function is decreasing
    deltax=grad/norm(grad)*step; 
    x=x-deltax';
    target2=target(x);
    if target2 > target1, x=x+deltax'; 
    step=step/10; 
    else,  target1=target2;
    end   
end
step=step0;

precision=norm(target1);
fprintf(1,'\n direction %d  precision %g',iii,precision);
if precision < eps, fprintf(1,'\n solution x =');
fprintf(1,'  %g',x); 
break;
elseif iii == itmax,fprintf(1,'\n ****precision could not be reached. Last 
point x =');
fprintf(1,'  %g',x); break;
end

end
  return
end
```

So to implement the steepest descent algorithm for nonlinear equation solving in C#, all I need to do is to somehow define that `target(x)` function from MATLAB in my C# program and I don't know how to do it, maybe someone could help me out?